# Why could there be high power usage, while low CPU and GPU usage?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, power-management, cpu-usage, zoom-meeting

When I use Zoom (under Windows 10 Pro), the coolers of my `Precision 5520` with `Xeon E3-1505M v6 CPU` begin working very hard and never stop. I decreased Zoom's priority in Task Manager to `below normal`. The Task Manager reports high power consumption by Zoom, but at the same time low CPU (about 15%) and GPU (about 5%) usage.

So my question is not about Zoom per se. The question is, how could there be high power usage, while low CPU and GPU usage?

Comment: I do not see this. Get the manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and check all your hardware. If my CPU is low (<5% or so) the computer is running very cool.

Comment: @John Would the test in BIOS be good for this?

Comment: You can try updating BIOS.   I have not seen low CPU leading to heating up

Comment: @John The CPU is in all 25% occupied, of which 15% is Zoom...

Comment: Even 25% CPU should not your coolers to work overly hard.

Comment: have you tried re-installing your chip set drivers with the latest ones from the manufacturers official website?